# WPF Menu item behaviour?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, behavior

I tried to look all around on the world wide web but with no success, I have a button in my application for opening a folder select dialog that it's implemented in that way:

```
        <Button Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" Content="Select Folder" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedLightButton}">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <FolderDialog:FolderDialogBehavior SetterName="FolderName"></FolderDialog:FolderDialogBehavior>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </Button>
```

Now i need this behavior (with another SetterName of course) in a Menu Item, but there is no way for me to find a solution to accomplish my task, can anyone please help me out?

```
<Menu Background="#292A24" Foreground="Yellow" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsMainMenu="True">
    <MenuItem  Header="_File" Height="35">
        <MenuItem Header="Export to csv">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Export" />
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Exit" InputGestureText="Ctrl+E">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="ExitToApp" />
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MenuItem has [its own Click event](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/windows/Controls/MenuItem.cs,220). So you have to create new behavior class for MenuItem

```cs
public class FolderDialogBehavior : Behavior<MenuItem>
{
    public string SetterName { get; set; }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.Click += OnClick;
    }
    
    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.Click -= OnClick;
    }

    private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        var result = dialog.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK && AssociatedObject.DataContext != null)
        {
            var propertyInfo = AssociatedObject.DataContext.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
            .Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite)
            .Where(p => p.Name.Equals(SetterName))
            .First();

            propertyInfo.SetValue(AssociatedObject.DataContext, dialog.SelectedPath, null);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to have single behavior class you can define subscription via reflection

```cs
private RoutedEvent _clickEvent;

protected override void OnAttached()
{
    var memberInfo = AssociatedObject.GetType().GetProperty("ClickEvent");
    if (memberInfo == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    
    _clickEvent = memberInfo.GetValue(AssociatedObject) as RoutedEvent
    if (_clickEvent == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    
    AssociatedObject.AddHandler(_clickEvent, OnClick);
}

protected override void OnDetaching()
{
    if (_clickEvent == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    
    AssociatedObject.RemoveHandler(_clickEvent, OnClick);
}
```